# Is there a way to use monogame 3.2 on visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, monogame

I have only a computer with 32 bit based windows and can't run versions of monogame higher than 3.2. To install monogame 3.2 I need visual studio 2013 or 2010 but I have 2015 and have not enough space to install 2013. Is there a way to install the templates of monogame 3.2 on visual studio 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: you're not getting the new Content Pipeline, so you will have harder time with building content, especially as you can't offload that to XNA either. The templates have nothing too magical, and you could manage with normal projects, just adding the assembly references and the `Game` class.

Now, to answer the question... Looking at the installer source code, I think the following *workaround* might work:

1. Go to your `Documents` folder. There should already be a folder named `Visual Studio 2015`.
2. Create the following folder tree: `Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#`
3. Run the installer. You should now be able to install Visual Studio 2013 templates.
4. Go to the folder you created in step 2. There should now be a folder named `MonoGame`.
5. Copy that folder to the `Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#` folder.
6. You should now see the templates in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Thank you! I don't really care for the content pipeline since I will most likely use it for Android games which I want just to try programming and have no big plans for them and I use xna for Windows games